# How to cook 1.5+ inch veal steak to medium?

Tags: steak, veal

It's a NY Strip part of a 12 month old calf. Hasn't been dry aged but I keep it 5 days in olive oil in a fridge. It has a bit of marble but way less than usual steaks could have. Pieces are pretty thick, 1.5 or more inch.

I was thinking searing them 2 minutes each side on high heat - say 7/10, both sides, then also sear the side edges. Then putting in the preheated oven on 400F for 10 - 15 minutes.

I don't have a thermometer to check so I'd need to be on the safe side that it's cooked, but also wouldn't like it to be well done.

Answer (score 7):

Go buy a thermometer. There is no possible way to be guaranteed to hit the perfect point where it is medium well done but not overdone without knowing the internal temperature. How quickly it cooks depends on things like the temperature in your oven (they are rarely precise), the exact thickness of the steak, its exact internal temperature when you first place it in the oven, and so on. You can find a functioning oven thermometer for $3-4 at your local super market, so there is really no reason not to buy one.

Comment: +1, but I would forego an oven or meat thermometer in favour of a quick-read digital probe thermometer. Much more accurate, much faster, much easier.

Comment: Ok, I will do that. But how about for the searing part, and on which temperature to set the oven?

Comment: You can guarantee perfect temperature without a probe thermometer, if you use a water bath.  Quickly sear over high heat, bag, place in a water bath (sous vide) at desired temperature (there are guides all over the net), remove from bag.  Quickly (30 sec) sear over very high heat.  Done.

Comment: @moscafj So you switch the problem from the temperature of the steak to the temperature of the water.

Comment: @LarsFriedrich it is certainly an option.

Comment: @moscafj No need for the initial sear if you go that route. I used to work in a restaurant that would sous vide thick veal steaks to rare (131 deg F if I remember right) and then finish them for ~2 minutes per side on the grill, which brought the interior up to perfect medium. Easily my favorite thing on the menu.

Comment: @logophobe there is a bit of research and practical advice that suggests both a pre sear and a post sear is better.  Starting the maillard reaction prior to the water bath means less time is necessary afterward for crust development, thus less of a chance of cooking the perfectly cooked product beyond the desired result.